# Using sed, tr, ... to fix the structure of a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal, tr

I have the file whose lines should be

```
U:<text>\tD:<text>\tA:<text>\n
```

where < text > is some text without tab or newline characters. \t is tab and \n is newline character. Unfortunately some < text > fields contain the newline character so the structure is broken. For example like this:

```
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
U:uu
    u    D:ddd    A:aaa
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
```

Here there was a newline character in the field U in the 3rd line, causing that some of the content that should be in 3rd line is now in 4th. How can I fix the structure with tools like sed or tr? I want to delete those newline characters that are not at the end of my record.

So for example above the fixed file should look like this:

```
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa
```

An other important aspect of the solution is the speed, since I have gigabytes of files to fix.

Comment: Can the `A:` text contain an erroneous newline?  Can any of the `<text>` sections contain `A:` or `U:` or `D:`?  How big is the file to be processed?  Is slurping the whole file into memory an option (files smaller than 1 GiB, say), or must it be done more piecemeal?  Will there always be leading spaces on the 'continuation' lines?

Comment: For now I only found extra newlines in U. But if the code can fix for potential extra newlines in D and A that is super, but if it can not it is also ok. There shouldn't be any A: U: and D: in text. It can be assumed that the file can be read in RAM. I acctually have thousands of files but each individual file is at most 2GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input data (saved in file `data`):

```
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa1
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa2
U:uu
    u     D:ddd     A:aaa3
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa4
U:uuu     D:dd
              d     A:aaa5
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa6
```

the `sed` script (saved in file `sed.script`):

```
/^U:.* D:.* A:.*/ { p; d; }
/^U:.* D:.*/ { N; s/\n *//; p; d; }
/^U:.*/ { N; s/\n *//; p; d; }
```

can be run and produces the output shown:

```
$ sed -f sed.script data
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa1
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa2
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa3
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa4
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa5
U:uuu     D:ddd     A:aaa6
$
```

The first line of the script looks for `U:`, `D:` and `A:` on a single line, assumes it is complete (and not a broken `A:` text field) and prints the line and deletes it (which skips the other actions in the script).  The second line looks for `U:` and `D:` only; the `A:` is presumably on the next line.  It appends the next line of input, removes the embedded newline and following spaces (if any), and then prints and deletes as before.  The third line looks for `U:` only and assumes both `D:` and `A:` are on the next line.  It appends the next line, removes the embedded newline and following spaces (if any), and then prints and deletes as before.

Extending it to handle breaks in the `A:` text field will be non-trivial.  It would also be non-trivial to extend it to handle:

```
U:uu
    u     D:dd
              d     A:aaa7
```

Neither is formally impossible (especially if you choose to use Perl or Python instead of `sed`), but not completely simple.  The double-split is simpler to handle; inside the third line, you'd have a second set of conditional actions based on whether the `A:` is found or not, etc.

Handling multiple splits for a single field:

```
U:u
   u
    u
           D:d
              d
               d
                      A:aaa
```

would also be tricky — probably doable, even in `sed`, but tricky.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Only one note: when copying the script you might get spaces between `U:.*` and `D:.*` which should be replaced by tabs.

Comment: Very fair comment; I tested with all blanks, not with tabs.  You could replace the `.*` with `[^<tab>]*` and the blank before the following `D:` or `A:` with a tab; rinse and repeat.  The newline might need to be followed by `[[:space:]]` or thereabouts, too, instead of blank-star. The key, though, is in the rest of the script, rather than the minutiae of the regexes handling of white space.

Comment: @Jonathan VG explanation